# SSErrorDomain, SKReceiptRefreshRequest, SKRequest did fail with error, code = 16, code = 110

Tags: ios, storekit, nserror

**iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled**

I am using the following method to check for failures of `SKProductsRequest` and `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

My question is specifically about `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`.  I am testing for two conditions, (1) when the user cancels the sign-in to iTunes Store for the receipt request and (2) when the user tries to sign-in and there is no connection (Air Plane Mode).

I get the following errors:

When there is no connection:

> Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=110 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x13c76d680 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1009 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=
>
> { your product ids and corresponding URIs here }
>
> , _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be
>   offline.}}}

When the user taps cancel:

> Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=16 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x13c6ac7b0 {Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError
>   Code=-7003 "(null)"}}

I have used the raw error codes to differentiate between the errors and trigger the appropriate UI events to handle the error state.  But I've been doing it without understanding what the underlying error is.

**The common error domain between the two is SSErrorDomain.**

*Could someone please elaborate on what the SSErrorDomain is and what framework it belongs to?  Also, could you provide some helpful documentation about all of the possible error codes for this domain?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Thx for taking interest.  I did not!  I can't find any documentation on SSErrorDomain, all I can see is the few error codes I've been able to create by switching to "air plane mode" or "cancelling while in the middle of the refresh request".  I am still looking and need help.

Comment: Interesting. After all of your testing, do you think the only 2 things that cause this are "air plane mode" or "cancelling while in the middle of the refresh request"? -  I worry it could be more and stops my customers from purchasing but not sure.

Comment: I am not sure, but that is all I was able to test.  Since then, I submitted my app and Apple approved it, you can check it out https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fifteen-fun/id1085830223?ls=1&mt=8, I tested the in-app. purchases multiple times, all seems to work okay.  I tested the receipt refresh request too, by re-installing the app., and signing in with my apple id. to my friends phone and I still can restore the purchases that I already made, no issues.

Comment: As far as product requests go, you have to send a request each time to check for any changes to your available products by Apple, before selling them.  My logic here is...  If you can't get the product list from Apple, then the user can't finish buying them anyway, because they either don't have a valid id. to sign in with or there is no reception.

Comment: Awesome thanks for letting me know. This is an annoying error but sounds like the live app's IAP works just fine. Thats what I'm experiencing too.

Comment: Radar has been filed suggesting this may be a typo: http://www.openradar.me/25502597

Comment: @PhilMitchell Very interesting!  Didn't think of that.  Maybe it is a type, but the integer value of the error codes that are generated do not match those of SKErrorDomain.